# IPTables SNAT + OpenVPN problem on reboot

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I am trying to create a LAN to LAN VPN using OpenVPN and two RHEL5 machines.  I have everything working, except that it fails after I reboot the client side(until I restart iptables).

The relevant openvpn configuration:

```
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote full.host.name 443
ifconfig 192.168.1.14 192.168.1.13
secret static.key
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

The relevant iptables configuration:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 192.168.2.53 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.14
```

I think it has something to do with iptables coming up before OpenVPN, and not being able to SNAT to an IP that it doesn't have yet.  How can I get this to work after a reboot without having to restart iptables?

Answer (score 0):

Your system does it start iptables at boot ? If not, ask it, in /etc/rcS.d or something like that (it depends of your distribution). It is strange that it is not enable by your ditribution. Do you have multiple firewalls on this machine ?

Comment: It does start iptables at boot.  The problem is that when I point another machine to it via a static route like: [192.168.2.53] --> [192.168.2.50] --OpenVPN-- [full.host.name] --> [192.168.1.0] : After a reboot it fails to NAT.  When I restart iptables it starts NATing again.  I think it is because 192.168.1.14 is the IP of the tun0 interface, which doesn't exist until OpenVPN starts.

Comment: iptables starts even if the interface is not up. To check, reboot, restart iptables, and then restart OpenVPN. Nat should be OK. I think there is a problem in the loading of iptables modules.

Comment: I'm not sure that iptables will run if the interface is no there and you are using SNAT/DNAT. Tray to use MASQ - in this case for sure the rule will be loaded even interface is not present at that time.